# Unable to launch application after updating to latest version of Visual Studio and Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am currently working on a Xamarin Forms application. The application was operating successfully until I updated Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin to the following:

Apple Developer Tools - Xcode 10.1
Xamarin.Mac - Version: 5.2.1.12
Xamarin.iOS - Version: 12.2.1.12

Now users are unable to open the application on their iOS devices. After install, when they click on the app icon the application launches and then immediately closes.

I have gone through the logs and found the following error:

```
error 09:40:36.951392 -0500 assertiond Failed to start job with error  <NSError: 0x7f97f2801640; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process">  
{ description = "Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:com.myapplication[0xca85][1468]";     
    failureReason = "No such process";     
    userInfo = 
{         
        BKLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:com.myapplication[0xca85][1468];         
        BKLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;     
    } 
}
```

I have checked the certificates (Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority, Developer ID Certification Authority, iPhone Developer, and iOS Distribution) all use system defaults.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, how did you resolve it?

Thank you

Comment: How did you distribution your app, in `App-Store` or use `Enterprise Certification`?Can you check if your `Distribution Certification` is expired? This is probably caused by your `Certification` is out of date.

Comment: It was the certificates in the end. I deleted everything and re-added them from App Store and now everything works. Thank you for your comment:)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the issue was with my certificates. I removed them all from Keychain Access and reinstalled them from the App Store. Now the application opens as it should.